# Is it possible to give a custom name and custom path for `runtime.exs` file

Tags: elixir

I found the runtime.exs file is in the config path and it is fixed.

But some configure value is customized in the client's environment, such as "serial port no". Is it possible to save these value, not flushed out when new version is deployed.

Is it possible to use local machines's local configure file such as '/usr/local/etc/myprogram.exs' replacing for default `runtime.exs`?
One stupid method is to parse the '/usr/local/etc/myprogram.exs''s every line and read every variable then update the configure environment variable? Does one more simple method exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply the application the needed configuration values from the system environment, e.g. using `System.get_env/2` or the stricter `System.fetch_env!/1`.  There are some options you can set in your application that affect the paths for configs, but their use may be subject to various caveats and confusion.

If you are looking for a more straightforward/conventional way to provide your application with runtime configuration, I would recommend use of the [dotenvy](https://hex.pm/packages/dotenvy) package: it is a port of the Ruby `dotenvy` package.  It adheres to the tenets of the "12-factor App", specifically the note to store configuration in the environment.  There are [articles](https://fireproofsocks.medium.com/configuration-in-elixir-with-dotenvy-8b20f227fc0e) about how to use this to enhance or even replace the sometimes confusing `config.exs`.  `dotenvy` allows you to provide multiple files to fulfill the environment's contract with the system: a `.env` file can be provided via version control or via a deployment tool like terraform, or the values can be set via a dashboard (such as Heroku).

Answer (score 1):

For system-specific configuration, I think it's better to use system environment variables for that, and read them using [`System.get_env/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13/System.html#get_env/2).

If you like, you can call `System.get_env` from inside `runtime.exs`:

```elixir
config :my_app, foo: System.get_env("FOO")
```

But you could also just call `System.get_env("FOO")` directly from your code instead of `Application.get_env(:my_app, :foo)`.

If you really want to use custom config files, check out [Multiple config files](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Config.Provider.html#module-multiple-config-files). But then you will have to start using releases. :-)